# How to configure ServiceStack.Text to use EnumMember when serializing to csv or jsv?

Tags: .net, csv, servicestack, datacontract, servicestack-text

This is a follow up question to my earlier question about [ServiceStack.Text and deserializing json to .Net enums](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51854666/10228027). The answer to that question resolves how to get ServiceStack.Text to use .Net [DataContract](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/using-data-contracts) and [EnumMember](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/enumeration-types-in-data-contracts) to map strings to enum values. Now I am trying to serialize the same enums to various formats and while json serialization is working in a round-trip way as expected, both csv and jsv conversion are ignoring the data contract. Is there a way to configure ServiceStack.Text (version 5.1.0, running on .Net Core 2.1) in a way so that the following code would produce the same result of all output types and so that the output would honor the defined data contract?

```
namespace TestNameSpace
{
    using ServiceStack;
    using System;
    using System.Runtime.Serialization;

    class TestClass
    {
        [DataContract]
        enum TestEnum
        {
            [EnumMember(Value = "enum_value")]
            EnumValue = 0,
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var testEnum = TestEnum.EnumValue;

            Console.WriteLine($"To json: {testEnum.ToJson()}");
            Console.WriteLine($"To csv: {testEnum.ToCsv()}");
            Console.WriteLine($"To jsv: {testEnum.ToJsv()}");
            Console.WriteLine($"To xml: {testEnum.ToXml()}");
        }
    }
}
```

The actual output is

```
To json: "enum_value"
To csv: EnumValue
To jsv: EnumValue
To xml: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><TestClass.TestEnum xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/TestNameSpace">enum_value</TestClass.TestEnum>
```

While I would like to see `enum_value` also in csv and jsv output. Is this possible with ServiceStack.Text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should now be supported from [this commit](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Text/commit/27a867505d23ec9ea386a6bc4a31123518049f3e) available from [v5.1.1 that's now on MyGet](http://docs.servicestack.net/myget).

Comment: Thank you! The latest 5.1.1 from MyGet indeed works now.