# How to deserialize nullable enum with EnumMember attribute in ServiceStack.Text?

Tags: .net, servicestack, datacontract, servicestack-text

This is a follow up question to my these two earlier questions about [ServiceStack.Text](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Text): [first](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51854666/how-to-configure-servicestack-text-to-use-enummember-when-deserializing), [second](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52001987/how-to-configure-servicestack-text-to-use-enummember-when-serializing-to-csv-or). As seen by checking answers to those questions, it is possible to serialize and deserialize enums based on their [data contract](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/using-data-contracts)'s and [EnumMember](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/enumeration-types-in-data-contracts) attributes. But what about nullable enumerations, i.e. `EnumType?` type. Using ServiceStack.Text, is it possible to serialize these using the EnumMember attribute? Using ServiceStack.Text 5.2.0, the following code:

```
namespace TestNameSpace
{
    using ServiceStack;
    using System;
    using System.Runtime.Serialization;

    class TestClass
    {
        [DataContract]
        enum TestEnum
        {
            [EnumMember(Value = "enum_value")]
            EnumValue = 0,
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            TestEnum? nullableEnum = TestEnum.EnumValue;
            Console.WriteLine($"nullableEnum.ToJson: {nullableEnum.ToJson()}");
            Console.WriteLine($"nullableEnum.ToCsv: {nullableEnum.ToCsv()}");
            Console.WriteLine($"nullableEnum.ToJsv: {nullableEnum.ToJsv()}");
            Console.WriteLine($"nullableEnum.ToXml: {nullableEnum.ToXml()}");
        }
    }
}
```

prints the following:

```
nullableEnum.ToJson: "EnumValue"
nullableEnum.ToCsv: EnumValue
nullableEnum.ToJsv: EnumValue
nullableEnum.ToXml: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><TestClass.TestEnum xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/TestNameSpace">enum_value</TestClass.TestEnum>
```

while I would expect all output formats to have `enum_value`. Is it possible achieve this with ServiceStack.Text?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Should now be resolved from [this commit](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Text/commit/24264279de64da9d492cf3e333297eb91f006773). This change is available from v5.2.1 that's now [available on MyGet](http://docs.servicestack.net/myget).

Comment: That's right, it works with 5.2.1 from MyGet. Thank you!